# 'cannot read _id of undefined' Mongoose promises .then()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise, bluebird

i am strugling with mongoose promises, i need to query data and query other data with that data as parameter

what im doing now :

```
var user_id;
var service_id;
var purpose_id;

User.findOne({name : 'demo1'}).exec().then(function(user){
    user_id = user._id;
    console.log('user')
    return Service.findOne({name : 'JollyClick'}).exec();

}).then(function(service){
    service_id = service._id;
    console.log('service')
    return Purpose.findOne({name : 'Newsfeed'}).exec(function(err, result){
        if(err) console.log(err)
    });
}).then(function(purpose){
    purpose_id = purpose._id
    console.log('purpose')
    DataUse.create({user : user_id, service : service_id, purpose : purpose_id}, function(err, datause){
        if(err) console.log(err)
    })

})
```

the values are correctly returned for the first 2 'then' but it throws an error for purpose_id, saying its undefined, it dont get why, ive been having the same problem all day, at some point i fixed one of it by changing the semicolons but  i dont know why it worked...

i have checked a simple query

```
Purpose.findOne({name : 'Newsfeed'}).exec(function(err, result){
    if(err) console.log(err)
});
```

does return a result

btw i am using mongoose and bluebird for promises

please help !
thank you

Comment: probably you have a problem here ` return Purpose.findOne({name : 'Newsfeed'}).exec(function(err, result){
        if(err) console.log(err)
    });` just return `.exec()` and use single `.catch` at the end of the chain

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, thats how my code was, i added the error handling to get an explanation, its the only way i know that 'purpose' is undefined, when i do catch (either after each exec or at the end) it doesnt show me anything
i will look into async await looks like it could save me a lot of trouble

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a callback function to `.exec` it does not return a promise anymore (or anything for that matter). That's why you get `purpose` being undefined.

Since you're already using promises you can chain `.catch` to handle errors instead.

```
return Purpose.findOne({name : 'Newsfeed'}).exec().catch(err => console.error(err));
```

You can do this if you need fine-grained error handling, but you can also chain a `.catch` to the entire promise chain if you want to catch any errors in the chain.

---

Depending upon the environment you are in you may be able to use `async`/`await`, particularly for node.js 7.10 or above.

```
async function createDateForUser() {
  const [{ _id: user }, { _id: service }, { _id: purpose }] = await Promise.all([
    User.findOne({name : 'demo1'}).exec(),
    Service.findOne({name : 'JollyClick'}).exec(),
    Purpose.findOne({name : 'Newsfeed'}).exec(),
  ]);

  return DateUse.create({ user, service, purpose }).exec();
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, thats how my code was, i added the error handling to get an explanation, its the only way i know that 'purpose' is undefined, when i do catch (either after each exec or at the end) it doesnt show me anything
i will look into async await looks like it could save me a lot of trouble

Comment: what would be the documentation for those functions please ?

Comment: i am getting an error in node v9 when defining a async function 'Syntax error : token function unexpected', do you know what causes it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var user_id;
var service_id;
var purpose_id;

User.findOne({name : 'demo1'}).exec().then(function(user){
    user_id = user._id;
    console.log('user')
    return Service.findOne({name : 'JollyClick'}).exec();

}).then(function(service){
    service_id = service._id;
    console.log('service')
    return Purpose.findOne({name : 'Newsfeed'}).exec();
}).then(function(purpose){
    purpose_id = purpose._id
    console.log('purpose')
    return DataUse.create({user : user_id, service : service_id, purpose : purpose_id}).exec()

})
.catch((err)=>console.log(err))
```

Like this way you just add `catch` at the end of the chain so in case any of the promises get rejected, it will be cached at the end

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, thats how my code was, i added the error handling to get an explanation, its the only way i know that 'purpose' is undefined, when i do catch (either after each exec or at the end) it doesnt show me anything
i will look into async await looks like it could save me a lot of trouble